Limit individual node dimensions inside a transformer when multiple nodes are selected
I'm using KonvaJS to manage a canvas with multiple nodes, and I've encountered a scenario where I need to control the dimensions of these nodes when using a Konva.Transformer.
Here's the situation:

I have multiple nodes on the stage, each with their own transformer. For example, some nodes have a bounding box of 200px height by 400px width, while others are 100px by 200px.

When I select multiple nodes, I apply a single Konva.Transformer to these selected nodes as described in the KonvaJS documentation.


The issue:
When I scale the transformer, it scales all the selected nodes uniformly. However, I would like to impose individual width and height limits on each node inside the transformer. For instance, Node A should not exceed 400px in width and 200px in height, while Node B should have its own set of constraints.
My questions are:

Is there a built-in way in KonvaJS to limit the dimensions of individual nodes when they are scaled via a common transformer?

If not, what would be the best approach to implement this functionality? Would I need to manually monitor the scaling event and adjust the dimensions accordingly?


